# Neo4J how to call db.index.fulltext.queryNodes on a nodes subset (instead of doing the search on every node in DB)?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, full-text-search

I have the following data model:

```
(org:Organization {name_en:'Org name in English', 'name_fr': 'Org name in French', 'anotherProperty': 'a value'})
```

I configured Full-text search index on the name's properties (name_en and name_fr).

If I want to make a fuzzy search on the name, I have to write the following:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("myOrgNameIndex", 'something~') YIELD node RETURN node
```

But, I always have to perform a first MATCH to get a subset of org nodes based on 'anotherProperty'. So instead of doing as first operation the fuzzy search on all org nodes of my DB (a lot...), **I would like first doing a MATCH with a WHERE and then calling the full-text search index based on the results of the 'first' query**.

How can I do that? Is it even possible?

Already thank you for your reply.

Comment: You need to add additional properties in full text index and use them in your query.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little late, but maybe in some cases, when `anotherProperty` is a constant, it would be a useful solution to reverse the problem.

First, add new label to desired nodes:

```
MATCH (org:Organization { anotherProperty : 'some value' })
SET org:SearchableOrganization
```

Create index on SearchableOrganization:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX myOrgNameIndex FOR (org:SearchableOrganization) ON EACH [org.name_en, org.name_fr]
```

And then do the search as previously on already reduced set :

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("myOrgNameIndex", 'something~') YIELD node RETURN node
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `WHERE` clause to the `CALL` , like this

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("myOrgNameIndex", 'something~') YIELD node 
    WHERE node.anotherProperty = 'foo'
RETURN node
```

Comment: Yes ok but unfortunately by doing this, the WHERE filter is done on the (potentially large) results set coming from the procedure call.

Comment: @koD yes, it seems so according to my profiler.. apparently Neo4j's db engine cannot reduce the scope of the lucene index I guess.